# Azure Xamarin Offline Sync - Multiple Tables/Threads

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, synchronization

for weeks now I try to get to nicely done TODO items offline sync sample in xamarin forms documentation to work for more than one tables with no lack, i think it's probably thread issue with sqlite.

So in the RefreshItems Method i have now 3 tables to refresh but it's always fail without even debugging helpful data...

```
> private async Task RefreshItems(bool showActivityIndicator, bool
> syncItems, bool isShowToday)
>         {
>             using (var scope = new ActivityIndicatorScope(syncIndicator, showActivityIndicator))
>             {
>                 var sf = await managerScheduleFlight.GetScheduleFlightsAsync(syncItems);
>                 
>                 var sc = await managerScheduleCrew.GetScheduleCrewsAsync(syncItems);
> 
>                 var c = await managerCrew.GetCrewsAsync(syncItems);
```

......

So in the second update

```
var sc = await managerScheduleCrew.GetScheduleCrewsAsync(syncItems);
```

it hangs.

Comment: How does it fail? How are you calling RefreshItems? Why are you not calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` and doing context switching so much?

Comment: I need to update UI from 3 tables (select and join) so that's was the obvious thing to try as i saw it.... i try to find some code example of the scenario that i need with no luck... What the ConfigureAwait(false) does?

Comment: i call the refresh items like this: private async void btnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RefreshItems(true, true, false);
        }

Comment: What do mean by "doing so much context switching.." - you mean by having 3 different managers for each table? should i try to have only one manager for all 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!!

Building 3 different managers was a bad mistake. join them all to one manager solved all the problems...

Thanks Cheesebaron for your HINT :)

```
 private async Task RefreshItems(bool showActivityIndicator, bool syncItems, bool isShowToday)
        {
            using (var scope = new ActivityIndicatorScope(syncIndicator, showActivityIndicator))
            {
                var sf = await manager.GetScheduleFlightsAsync(syncItems);

                var sc = await manager.GetScheduleCrewsAsync(syncItems);

                var c = await manager.GetCrewsAsync(syncItems);
```